# SQL insert into using WITH statement throws an unexpected 'insert' error

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As part of my SQL query, I first create a table called 'new' based on certain conditions and then `insert into` the `new` table some columns from a different table `old` based on certain conditions. Here's a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
   item    | subitem    |   stage    |   id     | 
    -----------------------------------------------
    i1      | s1         |  picked    |    1     |
    i1      | s2         |  shipped   |    1     |
    i2      | s4         |  picked    |    2     |
    i3      | s10        | shipped    |    2     |
    i3      | s11        | eligible   |    0     |
    i4      | s2         |not eligible|    0     |
    i1      | s1         |  picked    |    3     |
    i1      | s2         |  picked    |    3     |
```

I want the output as following:

```
    item1|subitem1|item2|subitem2|pair_volume|item1pick|item1ship|item2pick|item2ship|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    i1   |   s1   |  i1 | s2     | 2         |  2      | 0       | 2       | 1       |
    i1   | s1     | i2  | s4     | 1         |1        | 0       | 1       | 1       |  
    ....
    .....
    ....
```

Essentially, what I want to do here is the following:

I want to first make a cross-join of `item, subitem` with itself, so I have all possible combinations of `item1`, `subitem1` and `item2`, `subitem2`.

Here's how the stages are defined. If a stage is eligible, then it is just eligible, whereas if a stage is picked, then it means that item is both eligible and picked. If a stage is shipped, then it means that item is eligible, picked and shipped. Only the last stage is mentioned.

Now, for every `item1, subitem1 - item2, subitem2` pair, I want to calculate the count of `id` sessions where this pair occurs and has stage in `(eligible, shipped, picked)` and populate the value in `pair_volume`. For eg, `(i1,s1)-(i1,s2)` pair occurs twice (once in `id` 1 and once in `id` 3) and in both these `id` sessions, both the items in the pair were `eligible` (which is implied from `picked` and `shipped`) stages. Out of the 2 times that this eligible pair occurred, how many times is item1 picked, item2 picked, item1 shipped and item2 shipped? This is what I am trying to solve.

I can do fine until cross join. But I don't know how to insert values into the cross joined table. The real problem is more complex than what I have mentioned here. Any help is much appreciated!
Here's the query I have so far:

```
with new as
(
select combination.item1, combination.subitem1, combination.item2, 
combination.subitem2,
    (
    select tmp.item1, tmp.subitem1, tmp.item2, tmp.subitem2,
    case when ((tmp.item1 = tmp.item2) and 
    (tmp.subitem1 = tmp.subitem2)) then 'TRUE' else 
    'FALSE' end as indicator from
        (
        select distinct item as item1, subitem as subitem2
        from old
        cross join
        select distinct item as item2, subitem as subitem2 
        from old
        ) tmp
    ) combination
where combination.indicator = 'FALSE'
)
insert into new (pair_volume)
select count(id) as pair_volume
from old
where ((new.item1 = old.item) and (new.subitem1 = old.subitem) and 
stage 
in ('picked', 'eligible', 'shipped')) and
((new.item2 = old.item) and (new.subitem2 = old.subitem) and 
stage 
in ('picked', 'eligible', 'shipped')
```

This is essentially what I am trying to do here and the `insert into` statement keeps throwing error. The part until `cross join` works fine. But I am having trouble inserting values into the table as well as making the right conditions for the output table I want. Any help is much much appreciated!!

However, this throws an error for me as follows:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 4 at position 0 unexpected 'insert'.

I tried including a semi colon before the `insert into` statement, this is what I get:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 1 unexpected ';'.

I tried including a comma `,` before the `insert into` statement, this is what I get:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 4 at position 0 unexpected 'insert'. syntax error line 5 at position 0 unexpected 'select'.

What am I doing wrong here? Based on a lot of other posts, I figured this is how we use `insert into` with a CTE.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Given that your code is fine in SQL Server, I strongly advise you to tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: "*I first create a table called 'new'*" - a CTE does **not** "create a table". You also have simplified your example to a point where it doesn't make sense any more. As written, your code (for a DBMS where it works) is equivalent to `insert into old select * from old`

Comment: Let me rephrase my question for you guys

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I just updated my question simulating the actual example I am trying to solve instead of a simplified version.

Comment: So which DBMS product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? SQL Server? To me it seems you are just looking for `create table new as select ....` You can't insert into a CTE like that. You also say you want the "output" like that - then why an insert to begin with and not just a simple SELECT statement?

Comment: It's Snowflake computing. Guess it's SQL?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you are very close but a CTE doesn't create a table, which is why it doesn't work.

This bit is fine:

```
with new as
(
select combination.item1, combination.subitem1, combination.item2, 
combination.subitem2,
    (
    select tmp.item1, tmp.subitem1, tmp.item2, tmp.subitem2,
    case when ((tmp.item1 = tmp.item2) and 
    (tmp.subitem1 = tmp.subitem2)) then 'TRUE' else 
    'FALSE' end as indicator from
        (
        select distinct item as item1, subitem as subitem2
        from old
        cross join
        select distinct item as item2, subitem as subitem2 
        from old
        ) tmp
    ) combination
where combination.indicator = 'FALSE'
)
```

The next line:

```
insert into new (pair_volume)
```

You cannot insert into new. There is no table called "new". Even if you could insert into the CTE, there is no column called pair_volume.

You need to create a seperate table to contain the data output that you are creating.

Do you have a fixed number of subitems? If not, it becomes more complex and you will need to use dynamic SQL to build a query to get the result that you want, or if your RDBMS supports it you could use SELECT INTO to dynamically create a table from the resultset.

Comment: In standard SQL (which is what the `sql` tag refers to) a new table based on a SELECT statement is created using `CREATE TABLE new AS select ...` not with "into"

Comment: Both methods are valid. See here for SELECT INTO syntax https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: @iainc: Thanks for the response. This didn't work for me. I have included more details in my question to simulate the problem that I am trying to solve. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Well w3fools is known for its many errors - that's one of them. `select into` most definitely not standard SQL

Comment: @Gingerbread - the key is that you are trying to insert into the CTE table. You can't do that.

Comment: @iainc: Cool. I understand your point. But do you think this problem can be solved in any other way other than creating temp tables, by just using select sub queries?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not obliged to use `CTE` (basically using CTE does not make much sense when you want to create a new Table), you can try, like:

```
INSERT INTO new (tmp1, tmp2)
SELECT tmp1,tmp2
FROM old
```

**Edit:** Assuming SQL Server